# Joi validation - field required condition at runtime

Tags: typescript, hapi.js, joi

I'm using hapijs to write a microservice. I have an API that takes three parameters in the request body (POST method)

- UserID
- Last name
- Date of birth

I'm planning to do validation using JOI. The validation should be the following

1. The UserID should be required if both last name and date of birth are
   absent in the request
2. Both Last name and date of birth should be required if UserID is absent

I have tried to achieve that by following. It doesn't seem to work.

```
export const userRequestModel = Joi.object().keys({
    lastname: Joi.string().when('uid',
        {
            is: undefined,
            then: Joi.string().required()
        }),
    dob: Joi.string().when('uid',
        {
            is: undefined,
            then: Joi.string().required()
        }),
    uid: Joi.string().
        when('lastname',
        {
            is: undefined,
            then: Joi.string().required()
        }).
        concat(Joi.string().when('dob',
            {
                is: undefined,
                then: Joi.string().required()
            }))
});
```

The concatenation doesn't seem to be syntactically correct. It shows the below typing error

*Argument of type 'AlternativesSchema' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FunctionSchema'.Property 'arity' is missing in type 'AlternativesSchema'.*

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally this schema creates a circular dependency.

> Error: item added into group uid created a dependencies error

...an issue Joi has no elegant way of managing, especially when there's more than two keys. An extended discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/588) amongst other places.

A possible alternative would be something along the lines of:

```
Joi.alternatives().try(
    Joi.object().keys({
        lastname: Joi.string().min(1).required(),
        dob: Joi.string().min(1).required(),
        uid: Joi.string()
    }),
    Joi.object().keys({
        lastname: Joi.string(),
        dob: Joi.string(),
        uid: Joi.string().min(1).required()
    })
);
```

Which isn't pretty and could fall apart if the schema got more complex.

Comment: Thanks @Ankh for the answer. I got another suggestion from Joi community member WesTyler. Please take a look at https://github.com/hapijs/joi/issues/1271. It looks a bit more elegant.

Comment: Hi @Keerthivasan, thanks for the update, definitely learnt something myself from reading that!